# $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinality of any interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that any proper interval has the same cardinality of the reals numbers $\mathbb R$. In order to prove this I define two functions $f:(s,t)\to (u,v),f(x)=\frac{v-u}{t-s}(x-s)+u$ and $g:\mathbb R\to (-1,1),g(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$.

My question is are these functions bijections and from that can I conclude any interval has the same cardinality of $\mathbb R$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $g$ is not defined at $x=-1$.

Comment: @ThomasE. I changed the function, is it ok now? thanks for the remark.

Comment: The problem is a little different for *open* intervals $(a,b)$ than for closed intervals $[a,b]$, or half-open intervals.

Comment: The range of your new $g$ is not $(0,1)$. No big problem, you can work with $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas is it of now?

Comment: Yes, that's OK, it is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Your first function is a bijection and proves that any two finite intervals have the same cardinality.  Your second fails because $g(-\frac 12) \not \in (0,1)$ but you have the right idea.  There are many bijections between $\Bbb R$ and some finite interval.  One of the simplest is $\arctan(x)\to (\frac {-\pi}2,\frac \pi 2)$  This solves the open intervals.  For closed intervals, you need to "swallow" the endpoints somehow.

Comment: I changed the function, do you think it's a bijection now? thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Can you prove it?

Comment: I'm trying to do this right now.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a bijection because it is a linear function, and all linear functions are bijections (why?). For $g$ consider $\frac{x}{1+|x|}=\frac{x}{1+x}$ if $x \geq 0$. Its derivative is $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}>0$. This means $g(x)$ is increasing when $x \geq 0$. Note  the same is true about $g'(x)$ in the case $x<0$ and notice that $g(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Conclude.

Comment: I defined two functions $g_1:\mathbb R^+\to (0,1), g_1(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ and $g_2:\mathbb R^-\to (-1,0], g_2(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$

Comment: And I proved both are bijections or using the argument of @Darrin or seeing they are surjective and injective by the argument: $x/1+x=y/1+y\implies x=y$ for the first function and the second one is analogous.